# What can I do to improve kernel and overall performance?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, performance

With the latest major versions (15 & 16) my computer (top notch and recent hardware for 4000 Euro, all running on SSD Raid=1GB/sec) became unbearable slow.

Everything which was smooth is now jittery til complete freezing for 10+ seconds. I used to have 2 Virtual Machines running, some instances of Jetbrains with no problem at all.

I don't use any other apps than this and also didn't tweak any Ubuntu settings nor I do have lots of apps or background services installed.

The question: what can we do to improve performance? This is what I tried so far:

- removed all the bloat which usually Ubuntu is installing unasked with every major release
- disabled all unneeded services
- other display managers. **i tried 'flux-box' and all runs smooth and darn fast, for days.**
- investigated all logs but found no trace of bottlenecks or weird crashs  in dmsg
- checked with io-top and took measures like removing those high peak services/apps
- different NVIDIA drivers
- clean installations from scratch
- setting CPU affinity for powerapps like Virtual-Machine with windows-10 x64 guest
- different memory settings for Jetbrains
- running certain apps in a RAM disc

What could I do to optimize kernel settings? I am sure the defaults won't get all the juice out of my hardware.

Currently I even have to reboot every 1-2 hours because you can't even use the app-switcher anymore. Sometimes its so bad, the launcher hangs for a minute.

thanks a lot for any suggestion. I am really desperate and close to switch back to gnome or anything which works just.

Hardware - Specs:

- Intel Core i7-6700K @ 4.00GHz
- 2x2 Samsung SSD840 on 2 RAID-1
- 64GB - DDR3 Memory
- GeForce GTX 760

All with latest updates.

Comment: Can you please provide us your hardware specs?

Comment: Holy smokes! 64GB of RAM? With that amount of RAM, you can disable you swap file altogether.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue with the KDE desktop environment?

Comment: KDE? no, i loved to use it but it got pretty heavy 8 years ago. so i went back to gnome and then ubuntu. You think I should give it another try? I am anyway now at the edge of switching to something ultra small

Comment: thing seems to be related to unity because under X11 & fluxbox there is not a slight sign of 'weakness' to see. all stable for days as said